# Preventing components to mount on each render with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I want to prevent each component to get mounted on each rendering, I’m using React Router,

I changed loading them with `component={ComponentName}` to `render{() => < ComponentName />}` with no success.

It seems that this is the natural behavior, but I guess there mus be a way to change it

Here is my App.js

```
export default function App() {
    return ( 
        <div className = "App" >
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Route path="/" render={() => <Header />} />  
                <Route exact path="/" render={() => <ShowSplashWindow />} />  
                <Route path="/countries" render={() => <Countries />} />  
                <Route path="/createactivity" render={() => <CreateActivity />} />  
            </Provider>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And here are my routes paths:

```
                <nav className={style.nav}>
                    <Link to="/" className={style.subNav}>
                        <p>Init</p>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to="/countries" className={style.subNav}>
                        <p>Countries</p>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to="/createactivity" className={style.subNav}>
                        <p>Create Activities</p>
                    </Link>
                </nav>
```

I’ve searched the internet, it says that the render approach resolves the issue, but in my case it doesn’t

Rafael

Answer (score 0):

Use `Switch` component from `react-router-dom`. The [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) says:

> How is this different than just using a bunch of `Route`s? `Switch` is unique in that it renders a route exclusively. In contrast, every `Route` that matches the location renders inclusively.

```js
export default function App() {
    return ( 
        <div className = "App" >
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Route path="/" render={() => <Header />} />  
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" render={() => <ShowSplashWindow />} />  
                  <Route path="/countries" render={() => <Countries />} />  
                  <Route path="/createactivity" render={() => <CreateActivity />} />  
                </Switch>
            </Provider>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I tested it and didn't work, I placed a console.log('I'm here') in one of the components, Countries, and it shows on every render, say, I go to /createactivity, then go back to /countries, and the log shows